# How to make, the switch to change only when I click confirm `ok`

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How to make that the switch toggle change only when I click Ok in confirm box? When I click Cancel in confirm box, I want to change nothing.

My code html:

```html
<mat-card class="result">
  <mat-card-content>
    <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>
     <section class="example-section">
      <mat-slide-toggle
          class="example-margin"
          [color]="color"
          [checked]="checked"
          [disabled]="disabled"
          (click)="myfunction()">
        Slide me!
      </mat-slide-toggle>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

code ts:

```ts
export class SlideToggleConfigurableExample {
  color = 'accent';
  checked = false;
  disabled = false;
    myfunction() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to change Status?')) {
     }
  }
}
```

I tried and this code,

```html
<mat-slide-toggle
      class="example-margin"
      [color]="color"
      [checked]="checked"
      [disabled]="disabled"
      (click)="myfunction()"
      onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    Slide me!
  </mat-slide-toggle>
```

and remove  `if (confirm('Are you sure to change Status?')) {}` from ts.

In this I have this result:my function executed when I click `ok` and cancel.

Please, How to make, the switch to change only when I click confirm `ok`.

Thank you

Update:

Html code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myform" class="col s12">
<div *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp;let i = index">
            <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle value="active" formControlName="active-{{i}}" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"(click)="onActiveHomeboxP()"> {{item.active}}
            </mat-slide-toggle>
        </section>
</div>
</form>
```

ts code:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  public homeboxsp: HomeboxP[] = [];
  myform: FormGroup;
  checkedBtn: boolean;
  constructor(public service: Service) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateFormHomeboxP();
  }
  populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.homeboxsp = this.service.getData();


    let controls = {
      'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < this.homeboxsp.length; i++) {
      controls['active-' + i] = new FormControl(this.homeboxsp[i].active == '1', Validators.required)
    }
    this.myform = new FormGroup(controls);
    this.patchForm();
  }
  patchForm() {
    this.myform.patchValue({
      homeboxpackage_id: this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id),
    });
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.active))
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id))
  }
  onActiveHomeboxP() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      let edigps = this.myform.value
      console.log(edigps)
      console.log('true')
    } else {
      this.checkedBtn = !this.checkedBtn;
    }
  }
}
```

Image:
[image]

1. is checked because status is 1
2. is checked when I click **Cancel**
3. is checked when I click **Ok** in `consele.log('ture')`, show true

**Update:** When I add  `(ngModel)]="checkedBtn"`  in html, switches change all, not only one switch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the switch only when you press OK

In HTML:

```
<mat-slide-toggle  [(ngModel)]="checkedBtn" 
        (click)= "myfunction()"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

In TS:

```
myfunction() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

      console.log('true')

    }else{

      this.checkedBtn= !this.checkedBtn;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, can you look this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ky2qa?file=app/app.component.ts for this not works.

Comment: I couldn't run your stackblitz due to some proxy issue in my PC. But in your example where is the use of [(ngModel)]="checkedBtn" . You have not used the given example properly... Check my example again.

Comment: Have you any idea please?

Comment: you haven't used ngModel in your code still..how will it work..my example is working fine. Try to make it(the example) work first, then add your extra logics .

Comment: When I add `[(ngModel)]="checkedBtn"` switches change all, not only one switch. I update my post. Thnx

Comment: ok..but previously in your code there was only a single switch.. hence it was the answer...different approach needed to support multiple switch..and for that I think you need to raise new question...